# How can i use real back button functionallty in my back button programmatically?

Tags: android

i want to create a button which works like a real back button.When i press the back button(my button) this is work same with real button.How can i do programmatically?

Comment: Why are you wanting to create your own back button if it behaves exactly like the standard android back button?

Comment: @RichardLewin: i think some of HTC phones has not Back Button.

Comment: I know of no HTC phone without a back button as the back button has always been a 'standard' and needed button for an Android device. Only exception is recently where newer versions of Android creates a software based back button if there is none on the device (Mainly tablets though).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `onBackPressed()` [[docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29)] in the `onClick` handler of your button.

For example, use:

```
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 onBackPressed();
             }
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
    {       
        finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```